# CanResetPassword in User Model for Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am on the process of converting my app from Laravel 5.1 to 5.3. I am unsure on how to edit the `CanResetPassword` section in my User Model.

**This is the `user.php` file in my laravel 5.1:**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, SoftDeletes, CanResetPassword;
    ...
}
```

Now, I am not sure what edits are required when changing it to Laravel 5.3.

**Laravel 5.3 User model is like this:**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, SoftDeletes;
}
```

When I read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords), it said:

> Before using the password reset features of Laravel, your user must
>   use the Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable trait.

Which is already there.

> To get started, verify that your App\User model implements the
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword contract. Of course, the
>   App\User model included with the framework already implements this
>   interface, and uses the Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword
>   trait to include the methods needed to implement the interface.

I don't understand that since the first sentence says to implement the `CanResetPassword` contract but the second sentence says its already implemented. From the quote above, does it mean that I do not need to include `CanResetPassword` since the User Model already implements this interface?

Can someone show me what edit I need to do to the User Model in Laravel 5.3 for this Password resets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the docs say the `Authenticatable` class (`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`) actually includes the `CanResetPassword` trait. It also includes the `Authenticatable` and `Authorizable` traits as well.

The Laravel `5.3` example you have in your question is all you need.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @RossWilson The first line in doc got me confused `To get started, verify that your App\User model implements the CanResetPassword contract` while the second line states it includes the method already. Thanks for clarifying that for me. I will leave my User model as it is. Cheers!